# How initialise an angular service using a model?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I've created an angular service that will be used by all my "Task" component to stream data using `socket.io` :

```
@Injectable()
export class ChartService {
    private socket: SocketIOClient.Socket;

    constructor(task: Task) {
        this.socket = io(`${environment.api_url}tasks/${task.id}/data/socket`);
    }

    // HANDLER
    onNewMessage() {
        return Observable.create(observer => {
            this.socket.on('newMessage', msg => {
                observer.next(msg);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

How can I call the service from the task component ?
Right now, I'm calling the service as follwing :

```
export class TaskPreviewComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() task: Task;    

  constructor(
    private tasksService: TasksService,
    private chartService: ChartService
  ){}
...
```

But I don't know if I my allow to initialise the service with some specific data. My idea would be to call the service with the data e.g

```
private chartService: ChartService(task)
```

Comment: You need to use factory for `ChartService` that will create different instance for each provided task

Comment: Thanks! I'll be reading about factories, and will hopefully post an answer.

Comment: added answer with something I was using when I needed to have a multitone implementation. Although maybe I will also add an example of factory scoped to TaskPreviewComponent if you want?

Comment: The logic seems to work (integrated it, it runs flawlessly), but I'm still struggling with socket.io server-side. I'll try a few more fix to confirm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some more thoughts you may want use repository that may or may not use factory underneeth

```
@Injectable()
export class ChartServiceRepository {
  private services: { [key: string]: ChartService } = {};
  public get(task: Task) {
    if (!this.services[task.id]) { // same instance for every request
      this.services[task.id] = new ChartService(task); // if some additional injections are required you can use angular injector here (factory part)
    }
    return this.services[task.id];
  }
}
```

then you use it like this:

```
export class TaskPreviewComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() task: Task;    

  constructor(
    ...
    private chartServiceRepository: ChartServiceRepository 
  ){}
```

and somewhere further in the code

```
const chartService = this.chartServiceRepository.get(this.task);
chartService.onNewMessage();
```